# Is there ready to use multilingual string field for MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, multilingual, mongoengine

I'm looking for any opensource implementation of the multilingual StringField for MongoEngine.

I can do it by myself but if there is one I think it is better to use it and contribute to it may be.

What I want is the field that will know about various values of the same property in several languages, e.g.

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    name = MultilingualString()

my_doc = MyDoc.objects.first()

# storing value
my_doc.name.en = 'My Document'

# outputs stored value 'Mein Dokument'
print(my_doc.name.de)
```

I think it is pretty easy to implement such field using DictField internally.

P.S.: yes, it is really similar to the MongoKit's way.

Comment: You are going to have create that class if you want inheritance. Otherwise you can store an extra string containing the language "en" in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is for now.

["mongoengine-multilingual-field" project](https://github.com/lig/mongoengine-multilingual-field)

Usage:

```
from mongoengine import Document
from multilingual_field.fields import MultilingualStringField

class MyDoc(Document):
    name = MultilingualStringField()

doc = MyDoc(name={'en': 'Hermitage', 'ru': u'Эрмитаж'})
doc.translate('en')
doc.name  #  'Hermitage'
doc.translate('ru')
doc.name  #  u'Эрмитаж'
doc.translate('en')
doc.name = 'The Hermitage'
doc.name.translations  # {'en_US.ISO8859-1': 'The Hermitage', 'ru_RU.UTF-8': u'Эрмитаж'}
```

Here is what it looks like in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_cls" : "MyDoc",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5053ad4e3116b063001f6980"),
    "_types" : [
        "MyDoc"
    ],
    "name" : [
        {
            "lang" : "ru_RU.UTF-8",
            "value" : "Эрмитаж"
        },
        {
            "lang" : "en_US.ISO8859-1",
            "value" : "The Hermitage"
        }
    ]
}
```

It allows to define effective index by `(value, lang)` for fast value search and uses normalized locale names as lang codes.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't an implementation that I know of for this, however, after having a quick look at MongoKit - the data is stored as a dictionary and the setting current language is syntactical sugar on top of that.

Happy to take pull requests at http://github.com/mongoengine/mongoengine

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It will be soon. I will answer to this question by self when its done.